# Objective C - addobserver for UIView adding subviews?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, events, subview, addsubview

Is there an easy way for listening for when a child or subview has been added to a UIView?

I've gone through the addobserver options and haven't found an obvious option anyway. There may be another option that would be affected though when content is added to a view or am I wrong in saying that? i.e. content width or height, positions, etc.?

**Edit**
This is accomplished easily using the advice of @Alkimake below (**TextHolderClass**).
I created a custom UIView subclass and set the UIView's class in Interface Builder to be equal to **TextHolderClass**

Thanks for your help, I know it should have been obvious :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UIView has 2 methods to call after subview interactions. Simply create your custom `UIView` class and implement these methods which is pretty for you. And use your own `CustomView`

```
- (void)didAddSubview:(UIView *)subview;
- (void)willRemoveSubview:(UIView *)subview;
```

Comment: Cheers, I've done that and it's worked a charm. What I was trying to achieve in the first place is to listen to when the subview has been added and move an image on my UIViewController's interface to the right of the subview that was added. What is the best way to go about this now that I am using a separate class to respond to the event?

Comment: I've sorted this issue out now thankfully [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9115745/manipulating-ui-elements-from-within-a-class-method)

Answer (score 4):

`UIView` methods may help you:

```
- (void)willMoveToSuperview:(UIView *)newSuperview
```

Comment: Is that supposed to be called automatically? As in can I just add that method to my implementation file and it should be called when a subview is added/removed to/from the UIView?

Comment: Yes, if you implement this method in your subclass of UIView, it will be called automatically - however, this method is called when itself is added to a superview, not when you add subview to it. @Alkimake gave you the methods for that.